# CountDownLatch blocking Asnychronous Callback

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, countdownlatch

I have the following construct in code

```
public boolean do(){
    final boolean[] returnValue = new boolean[1];
    final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);

    event.addListener(new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange");
            returnValue[0] = true;
            cdl.countDown();
        }
    });


    try {
        if (cdl.await(1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) { 
            return returnValue[0];
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

What happens is the `CountDownLatch` waits for 1 Minute and then the Listener triggers. But since the latch has already counted down `false` is always returned. To me it seems as if the Latch is blocking the entire thread and not letting the Async Callback happen. 
I have tried wrapping the `event.addListener()...` part in a `Runnable` but the Problem persists.

I have the exact same construct in another part of my code and there it works.

Edit:
I have put Logs for `Thread.currentThread().getId()` and it does, in fact, evaluate to the same Id. Shouldn't the Async Callback be in a different Thread?

Comment: Do we agree that you assume that within 1 minute you expect the method onDataChange to be called right? If so can you see it in your log file?

Comment: Yes I expect the method onDataChange to be called in within the timeframe of 1 minute. I can see the call in the logfile AFTER the minute has passed. After my edit I believe it has something to do with Threading, but this looks very weird to me.

Comment: I believe that you should provide more code, to let us know how you call the method do() and how this even is triggered